VBA Message Box To Choose What XLA File To Attach
So we have a legacy spreadsheet that isn't going anywhere anytime soon. I've maintained two of them because there are times when we need different code to import a job. Upon opening the sheet, it attaches either one called Shipper.xla or on the second sheet, Shipper_Project.xla.
I'd like to just have on workbook to handle both XLA files depending on the job...so before it attaches, I created a MsgBox to ask if it is a Project Job? If yes, it attaches the Shipper_Project.xla, if no, it attaches the shipper.xla. If I hit yes, it works but still attaches the Shipper.xla.
EDIT - The Full Open Workbook Sub
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
    DoEvents
'    IsFontInstalled
    Sheets("Cover").Visible = True
    Sheets("COVER").Select
'==>TESTING PURPOSES ONLY
'    strFilePath = "D:\Importer\Fork 2008-05-21\Shipper.xla"
'    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile strFilePath
'<==
    result = MsgBox("Is This An MBS Project Job?", vbYesNo)
    If result = vbYes Then
        AttachXLAProject
    Else
        AttachXLA
    End If
    
    Select Case UCase(WindowCaption(Application.ActiveWindow))
        Case Is = "SHIPPER"
            AttachXLA
        Case Is = "SHIPPER.XLS"
            AttachXLA
        Case Else
            frmUn_Hide.Show
    End Select


    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

And the two Corresponding AttachXLA's...
Sub AttachXLA()
    With CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
        If UCase(.UserDomain) = "PINNSTR" Then
            strFilePath = "\\fileserver\Utility$\Internal\ShipperCode 3.0\Shipper.xla"
        Else
            strFilePath = "\\OMAAC-Server\Pinnacle\Shipper\Shipper.xla"
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile strFilePath
    End With
End Sub

Sub AttachXLAProject()
    With CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
        If UCase(.UserDomain) = "PINNSTR" Then
            strFilePath = "\\fileserver\Utility$\Internal\ShipperProjectCode\Shipper_Project.xla"
        Else
            strFilePath = "\\OMAAC-Server\Pinnacle\Shipper\Shipper.xla"
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile strFilePath
    End With
End Sub
    

It also says this after running the Yes/No box...

Now, in theory, I can name them both shipper.xla since they are saved in different parts of the file server, but I still need the selection to be made at start. I've tried ElseIf and EndIf and it just makes it worse for some reason.
Any suggestions?

Your code is not complete (it starts in the middle of ... something? ...). Also you have not explained what the problem is with this code either - does it work? If not, what is the error or problem?

What does "makes it worse" mean?  You haven't told us anything about what actually happens.

I updated the code in the original post?

Choose Add-in

Make sure the add-ins have distinct names. Also, they cannot be called VBAProject.
This will also remove the other add-in if it was (accidentally) added.

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ChooseAddin Me
End Sub

To Test in Open Workbook
Sub Tester()
    ChooseAddin ThisWorkbook
End Sub

Main
Sub ChooseAddin(wb As Workbook)
    Dim Result As Long: Result = MsgBox("Is This An MBS Project Job?", vbYesNo)
    If Result = vbYes Then AttachXLAProject wb Else AttachXLA wb
End Sub

Help
Sub AttachXLAProject(wb As Workbook)
    Dim FilePaths() As Variant: FilePaths = VBA.Array( _
        "\\fileserver\Utility$\Internal\ShipperProjectCode\Shipper_Project.xla", _
        "\\OMAAC-Server\Pinnacle\Shipper\Shipper.xla")
    AttachAddin wb, FilePaths
End Sub

Sub AttachXLA(wb As Workbook)
    Dim FilePaths() As Variant: FilePaths = VBA.Array( _
        "\\fileserver\Utility$\Internal\ShipperCode 3.0\Shipper.xla", _
        "\\OMAAC-Server\Pinnacle\Shipper\Shipper.xla")
    AttachAddin wb, FilePaths
End Sub

Sub AttachAddin(wb As Workbook, FilePaths As Variant)
    
    Dim refs As Object: Set refs = wb.VBProject.References
    
    Dim ref As Object, Index As Long, i As Long
    
    With CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
        Index = (UCase(.UserDomain) = "PINNSTR") + 1
        For i = 0 To UBound(FilePaths)
            If i = Index Then
                AddReferenceByPath wb, FilePaths(i)
            Else
                RemoveReferenceByPath wb, FilePaths(i)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub

Sub AddReferenceByPath(wb As Workbook, ByVal Path As String)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Add Reference By Path"
    
    Dim refs As Object: Set refs = wb.VBProject.References
    
    Dim ref As Object
    
    For Each ref In refs
        If StrComp(ref.FullPath, Path, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' exists
    Next ref
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    Set ref = refs.AddFromFile(Path)

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Could not add a reference to """ & Path & """!" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Sub RemoveReferenceByPath(wb As Workbook, ByVal Path As String)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Remove Reference By Path"
    
    Dim refs As Object: Set refs = wb.VBProject.References
    
    Dim ref As Object
    
    For Each ref In refs
        If StrComp(ref.FullPath, Path, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For
    Next ref
    
    If Not ref Is Nothing Then ' reference found
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        refs.Remove ref
    'Else ' reference not found
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Could not remove the reference to """ & Path & """!" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

